# Can't find the VM created from Resource Manager Template in manage.windowsazure.com

Tags: azure

I create a VM from resource manager template in powershell. And it returns successfully.
I can see it in https://portal.azure.com, but can not find it in https://manage.windowsazure.com .
in https://portal.azure.com, the VM is Virtual Machine(V2).

My question is:
1. why the VM created by resource template is Virtural Machine(V2)?
2. why this kind of VM can not be showed in https://manage.windowsazure.com ?

Here is part of the resource template:

```
    {
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('newStorageAccountName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
            "computername": "[variables('vmName')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
                "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
                "sku" : "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
                "version":"latest"
            },
           "osDisk" : {
                "name": "osdisk",
                "vhd": {
                    "uri": "[concat('http://',parameters('newStorageAccountName'),'.blob.core.windows.net/',variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'),'/',variables('OSDiskName'),'.vhd')]"
                },
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage"
            }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM Templates create IaaS v2 VMs only visible in the preview portal or ARM mode PowerShell cmdlets